# visp_tracker /object_position dimension

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
I have followed the http://wiki.ros.org/visp_tracker tutorial.

Then, I can changed this tutorial by creating my own .launch file, where I give to the node the params I need for get images from my cams.

Now, I want to control the head of my robot, and for that I have developed a rospy node which subscribe to /object_position but the point is (and sorry if it is a obvius question) that I don't know and I haven't found it, which are the position and rotation dimensions. I mean, this position, I assume that are not in real world coordinates, but in scalated pixels?

How can I convert this values to real world values in order to develop my control?

Thanks for your answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264146/visp_tracker-/object_position-dimension/) by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on 2017-06-20**:
Well, I have been looking around, and I have found this website: http://visp-doc.inria.fr/doxygen/visp-2.9.0/tutorial-calibration.html
With this, what I am not sure now, is what information is given by /object_position with two vectors: Position {x, y, z} and Rotation {x, y, z, w}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok! I am going to solve this issue myself.
The fact is this /object_position in deed returns the actual object position in meters.
My main issue was that I had done a calibration for stereovision in place of a calibration for each camera.

---

Originally posted by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) with karma: 25 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0